# Slow AD-LDS connection with the PrincipalContext-class via LDAP in SSL

Tags: adam, principalcontext, adlds

On my dev machine I had to install an AD-LDS. In principal it works fine, however is the first connect to the AD-LDS via the PrincipalContext-class extremely slow (30 seconds+). It seems to me that it first tries to connect to some non existing host or directory and then after a timeout (the 30 seconds) connects to my AD-LDS and does what it is supposed to do.

The same behavior I observe when connecting with LDP.exe and SSL. However with ADSI-Edit, connecting via SSL is super-fast. So are connects via non-SSL.
I looked if I could see something in fiddler, but there was nothing. Also in the event-log I can find nothing. Maybe it has something to do with the certificate lookup? It is self-signed with makecert.

**Update**
In the meantime I have observed one little thing that maybe gives a hint: In the system event-log, the first time an SSL-connection to the AD-LDS is established, the following message appears:

*Name resolution for the name _ldap._tcp.[`machineName`]  timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded*

However, the message is only registered once, but every connect to the server takes the 30secs+. I also tried to enter corresponding entries in the hosts-file, but nothing changed.

**Additional info**
Probably it's not a problem with the certificates but maybe it helps solving the problem. Therefore here the way I created the certificates (more or less cargo-code):

*RootAuthority*

```
makecert -pe -n "CN=MyDevRootAuthority" -ss my -sr LocalMachine -a sha1 -sky signature -r "MyDevRootAuthority.cer"
```

*Server-certificate*

```
makecert -pe -n "CN=[MyComputerName]" -ss my -sr LocalMachine -a sha1 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -in "MyDevRootAuthority" -is MY -ir LocalMachine -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 "MyTestCertificate.cer"
```

After creation I moved the root authority  to the trusted authorities and granted the required permissions.

Comment: if you ipconfig /all to see your dns servers do you have any registered that you cannot reach? Also, do you have "Automatically detect settings" selected in Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings?

Comment: @ghangas: Thanks for your suggestion. Sadly, no unreachable DNS-servers are configured. For the LAN-Settings, I don't know which one you mean. But the network-adapter is configured to get it's configuration via DHCP and the same for DNS (what works as expected) [Network Settings->Ethernet->Adapter Options].

Comment: If your computer is configured to automatically detect proxy settings you can end up with this behavior while a search for http://wpad.domain.com/wpad.dat times out.

Comment: @ghangas: I tried it, however the behavior was the same. But thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After having the problem recently, I dug a little deeper and found, that using the `ContextOption` `ServerBind` while constructing the `PrincipalContext` solved the problem reliable, except for the `ValidateCredentials`-method on the context.

**Alternative way with SDS.P**
Additional information: Working with SDS and SDS.AM was for me always complicated. It costs a lot of time thanks to the often unrelated and inaccurate error-information given by its components (due to the complex inner hierarchy of the used system components (ADSI)).
Eventually, I moved some code to the SDS.P namespace and although there is little information in the internet on how to work with, it seems somewhat more proper and nice. I cannot speak for everyone or every domain, but moving from the ADSI-based components to SDS.P (wldap32.dll based) has simplified and clarified a lot for me. And it even works asynchronously for the most of its parts. And as a bonus, it's super fast.
A good starting-point is here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx

**Old solution**
The problem comes from the circumstance, that my dev computer was not part of a domain. I saw this after we tried the same thing on a domain-integrated machine and the problem didn’t happen.

***Solution (for non-AD-embedded computers)***
**Code**
In code, to connect with `DirectoryContext`, the host-name must be specified with the dns-suffix “.local”.

```
[machinename].local
```

**Network Adapter**
Additionally, in the network-adapters settings in the “Advanced”-window, under the “DNS”-tab, the “local”-suffix must be registered as the DNS suffix for the connection’s DNS addresses.
[image]

**Certificate**
The certificate however, I had not to change.